# How to Integrate PHP website & .Net website with SSO

Tags: php, asp.net, ldap, single-sign-on

We have developed an 2 websites . one website in PHP  ( Customer feedback portal). Another product based web application in .NET ( ASP.NET & MVC). We would like to integrate the customer feedback portal in the product based web application with SSO.

Can any one share your ideas at least in the high level.

How we can achieve this.

Thanks
Mohamed

Answer (score -2):

You can use authentication protokol like kerberos for both systems.

I think this is a better way instead of writing something custome, share sessionIds (an example) etc ...